# "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Icon' in 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'"

Tags: c#, winforms

So I was working on my Visual Studio project, but when I tried to add my own Icon for my app it prompts that error and won't let me run my app. Any kind of help is appreciated.

I tried adding this code snippet:
`Icon ico = new Icon("myiconfilepath"); this.Icon = ico;`
but nothing changed, the error still appears.

Comment: I doubt that that's the actual error message, but the difference may be incidental. Do you have any `Label` controls on that form? If so, what are they named? Is there a particular reason that you're setting the form's `Icon` in code rather than in the designer?

Comment: I'm quite novice to VS and i'm not sure what do you mean by label controls, want me to share the explorer tree? I tried setting the form's Icon by the properties window btw, then tried adding that code snippet but got the same error.

Comment: `Labels`, like `TextBoxes`, `Buttons` and `Labels`. Did you add any to the form? If you set the `icon` in the designer then why would you add the code back? The point is to set it in the designer INSTEAD OF doing it in code. You don't need to do it in code unless you need to change the `icon` from its initial value after the form has loaded.

Comment: _Just like the dream of turning lead into gold, sadly one cannot convert one .NET type into another without an implicit converter...which Icon doesn't have for Label._  You are comparing apples and oranges sadly.   I suspect you have a typo somewhere.